# Regex with substitutions using sed|awk and groups

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I have this input text

```
16789248,16789759,"AS24155 Asia Pacific Broadband Wireless Communications Inc"
```

I want this text

```
"AS24155","Asia Pacific Broadband Wireless Communications Inc"
```

This regex matches

```
 /(.*)(AS\d+)(\s)([^"]+).*/g
```

with this substitution `"$2","$4"`

I have to process 300k lines and it would be best if I was able to use a linux based command line utility like sed or awk...but I keep getting no matches or matches even though the regex seems to match elsewhere.

Should I be using something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed -r` can handle it with a few modifications: `[0-9]` instead of `\d` and `<space>` instead of `\s`. There's no real reason to capture the first and third parts, so I've removed those groups.

```
sed -r -e 's/.*(AS[0-9]+) ([^"]+).*/"\1","\2"/'
```

Or if you want to match those character classes exactly, use `[[:digit:]]` for `\d` and `[[:space:]]` for `\s`:

```
sed -r -e 's/.*(AS[[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]([^"]+).*/"\1","\2"/'
```

Alternatively, you could use `csvtool` which is more suited to the job of parsing CSV files than `sed` is.

```
csvtool col 3 input.txt | while read number name; do
    printf '"%s","%s"\n' "$number" "$name"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[^"]*"/"/;s[[:space:]]/","/'
```

based on your sample and avoiding the problem of group

Answer (score 0):

sed is the best choice for this but FYI here's how you could use almost your exact RE in GNU awk to do the job:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/.*(AS[0-9]+)\s([^"]+).*/,a){printf "\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", a[1], a[2]}' file
"AS24155","Asia Pacific Broadband Wireless Communications Inc"
```

Your original command was probably failing because only some tools accept `\s` instead of `[[:space:]]` and almost none accept `\d` instead of `[[:digit:]]` (or `[0-9]`).